# How to generating waveform from video & show it with video

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, ffmpeg, waveform

We are using Rails as a backend & AngularJS on Front End side in my App where we need to show Video & audio waveform of that video.

We are using 'wavesurfer.js' to show the waveform on Front End side & 'node-pcm' to generate pcm from video file on BackEnd side.

This is working as expected but in some of the videos while creating waveform from pcm data instead of showing small sine waves we get flat line.
Also it takes too much time to show the waveform for every page reload.

To overcome this issue we are planning to create waveform image using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/aadasdsadsadasdas/xyz.mp4' -filter_complex showwavespic -frames:v 1 output.png
```

This is working fine but it also takes too much time (Ofcourse only once ) to generate the image for remote video (i.e. We are saving videos on S3)

Problem with this i don't get any library to integrate the waveform image with the Video.

Can someone suggest any better approach related to this.

Comment: can you detail the "integrate the waveform image with the Video" part please?

Comment: Sure, i mean as per the current implementation as video is in progress a vertical line is also progresses over the waveform. Also color of the waveform also changes. Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: There's a [waveform.js plugin for video.js](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-wavesurfer) that might help. [Video demo](https://collab-project.github.io/videojs-wavesurfer/examples/video.html)

Comment: Yes, i already using it (As mentioned in the question) but it didn't support the image video waveform :(.

Comment: you mentioned you used the `waveform.js` lib. This is a waveform plugin for the `video.js` video player, and it supports video as seen in the example above.

Comment: @aergistal Somehow its not working for me.....i am still working on it.....will i get to see video as well as it's audio waveform at the same time ?